# Characterizations of the GOE/GUE family of distributions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, random-matrices

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71306/when-should-we-expect-tracy-widom). Loosely speaking, when should I expect a GOE/GUE distribution? The angle of my approach to this is not through statements such as "there is a natural inverse-distance repulsion between particles." Rather, I'm interested in how to characterize GOE/GUE through their projections, symmetries and invariances.

For a random symmetric matrix of size $n\times n$, with entries drawn from a Gaussian Ensemble, the joint probability of eigenvalues can be written as:

$$\rho_{\beta,n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=C_{\beta,n}\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq N}|x_j-x_i|^\beta\prod_{i=1}^ne^{-\beta x_i^2/2}, \ \beta=1,2,3,4\ldots$$

where $\beta$ depends on the specific type of ensemble ($\beta=1$ for GOE, $\beta=2$ for GUE, etc.).

Now, suppose that $X_i$ $(i=1,2,\ldots,n)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that the joint distribution of the vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is invariant under rotations. Then the vector must be Gaussian.

Here's another characterization of Gaussians: If $Z$ is Gaussian and $X,Y$ are independent r.v. such that $Z=X+Y$, then $X,Y$ must be Gaussian. This is also known as Cramer's theorem.

There are many more characterizations of Gaussians.

> **Question:** Are there some nice characterizations of the
>   $\rho_{\beta,n}$ distributions? I would be particularly interested in
>   the case of GOE ($\beta=1$). Moreover, I would love to see
>   characterizations relying on symmetries, invariance or projections. If
>   these properties exist, have there been usage of these techniques in
>   the literature to show a certain distribution is from a Gaussian
>   Ensemble?

Edit: I should add here that the characterizations I'm looking for should preferably not be related to characterizations of the random matrix ensemble involved. For example the GOE has a distribution that's invariant under orthogonal similarity transformations. I say this because in some problems, a connection to random matrix theory is nonobvious but numerically one sees the statistics are the same.

Here is an example. Take $n$ Brownian bridges starting at $0$ at $t=0$ and ending at $0$ at $t=2$. Now condition them to not intersect. Then the distribution of particle locations at $t=1$ is exactly the same as the GUE eigenvalue distribution. Now, of course there are well known ways of connecting these bridges *directly* to random matrix theory through the notion of determinental proceeses. However, suppose I didn't know of an immediate connection. Could I somehow convince myself that the GUE distribution is a good guess for this process?

Comment: If I recall, the only models for which there are any known group symmetries are $\beta = 1,2,4$ corresponding to orthogonal, unitary, and symplectic transformations.  Last I heard, Chris Sinclair was trying to show that the square integer processes are hyperpfaffian.  I think all that is really known about the rest of those processes is that there exists a matrix model for which that is the eigenvalue process.  The general $\beta$ ensembles are not really physical unless you interpret them as log-gasses with Coulomb interaction at inverse temperature $\beta$ in a Gaussian potential.

Answer (score 3):

to answer your first question, I could just follow your line of argument and take an ensemble of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices $A$, with real ($\beta=1$), complex ($\beta=2$) or real quaternion matrix elements ($\beta=4$). If I am told that the distribution of $A$ is invariant under orthogonal ($\beta=1$), unitary ($\beta=2$), or symplectic ($\beta=4$) transformations, and that the numbers $a_{kl}=(1+\delta_{kl})^{1/2}A_{kl}$ ($1\leq k\leq l\leq n$) are i.i.d. random variables, then the eigenvalues $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$ of $cA$ have your distribution $\rho_{\beta,n}$ for some $c\geq 0$.

your second question: is this useful --- this characterization is at the basis of algorithms to generate random numbers $x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n$ with the distribution $\rho_{\beta,n}$, which would be very cumbersome to generate directly.

Comment: Thanks, the second part is particularly enlightening. I've added a slight edit to the question. Basically, is there a non-random matrix characterization of these distributions?

Comment: non-random matrix characterizations: $\rho_{\beta,n}$ is the Gibbs distribution of a one-dimensional Coulomb gas in a harmonic confining potential, at temperature $1/\beta$, but that does not single out the special values $\beta=1,2,4$; any such characterization will somehow have to involve the Jacobian from matrix elements to eigenvalues, how could this arise otherwise?

Comment: That's a great question. I'm not entirely if what I'm asking for is reasonable. I've added an example below my edit which I think encapsulates what I'm after.

Comment: Carlo's Gibbs measure+ requirement to be determinantal characterizes, I believe but have not double checked, $\beta=2$. The $\beta=1$ and $\beta=4$ can be characterized by decimation relations.