# GOE convergence

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics

As is well-known (at least in some circles), eigenvalue spacing distribution for large symmetric matrices converges as size goes to infinity (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159987/characterizations-of-the-goe-gue-family-of-distributions) for more background). The question is: how quickly is it known to converge, and is the convergence faster for spacings in the "middle" of the spectrum (presumably there are weird edge effects which muck things up)?

Comment: not sure if this is what you're asking, but the "Wigner surmise" for the spacing distribution is derived for a 2x2 matrix and is almost indistinguishable from the large-N limit.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I was not aware of that, but there is still a couple percent difference between the Wigner surmise and the limit distribution, so that if you have reasonably large samples from both, they will look different enough for, say Kolmogorov-Smirnov to be sure that the distributions are different. But maybe that's no longer true for, say $10000x10000$ matrices?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[On the convergence of the nearest neighbour eigenvalue spacing distribution for orthogonal and symplectic ensembles](http://www-brs.ub.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/netahtml/HSS/Diss/SchubertKristinaBeatrice/diss.pdf), K.B. Schubert (2012).

> In this thesis we consider the empirical distribution of the spacings
>   of adjacent eigenvalues. In particular, we study the expected
>   Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance $D$ of the empirical spacing distribution
>   from its limit as the matrix size $N$ tends to infinity. We find that
>   $D$ converges with rate $N^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Wow, right on the nose!