# Extrapolation between longest increasing and longest alternating subsequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations

The question
[When should we expect Tracy-Widom?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71306/when-should-we-expect-tracy-widom)
motivated me to post the following question, in which I have been
interested for a while.  Let $f(n)$ be a function from the positive
integers to themselves. Given a permutation $w=a_1\cdots a_n\in S_n$,
let $m=f(n)$ and let $L_f(w)$ be the length $k$ of the longest
subsequence $b_1 \cdots b_k$ of $w$ satisfying
  $$ b_1<b_2<\cdots <b_{m+1}>b_{m+2}>b_{m+3}>\cdots>b_{2m+1}<b_{2m+2}<
      \cdots <b_{3m+1}>\cdots. $$
If we scale $L_f$ suitably then it should approach a limiting
distribution $\Phi(t)$ as $n\to\infty$. For $f(n)=1$ it is known that
$\Phi(t)$ is Gaussian. For $f(n)=n$ it is known that $\Phi(t)$ is the
Tracy-Widom distribution. See for instance
http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/ids.pdf (Theorems 4 and 14). What
happens in between these two extremes, e.g., $f(n)=\log n$ or
$\sqrt{n}$?  Do we always get either a Gaussian or Tracy-Widom
distribution? If so, what is the crossover point? If not, what other
distributions are possible?

Comment: In the interest of clarity, can you tell us what w is and what w and the a's have to do with L_f(w) ?  Also, I am guessing that f(n) > n is an f that plays no role in this problem.  Or can it?

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: I have added the fact that $w=a_1\cdots a_n$. The case $f(n)>n$ is equivalent to $f(n)=n$.

Comment: A trivial observation: there's some strange parity here. The Tracy widom distribution is biased toward one side, whereas the Gaussian is symmetric about the mean. This is evident here since for small $m$, we basically have reflection symmetry. So I would expect the transition to occur when $m\gg n/2$.

Comment: In particle systems or random matrices the phase transition from Gaussian to Tracy-Widom is known, it is given by Baik-Ben Arous-Peche distribution (or maybe in this case GOE Tracy-Widom which is a particular case)